# Does 'connected surface' in differential geometry actually mean 'path-connected surface'?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, definition

While studying differential geometry I often come across propositions with $M$ being a connected surface as their hypothesis. They then often take paths between arbitrary points, which to me suggests that they actually mean that $M$ is path-connected.

Is this true? Is it some sort of convention in differential geometry to not distinguish between normal- and path-connectedness?

Comment: Elementary topology says that connected plus locally path-connected implies path-connected.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332108/showing-that-every-connected-open-set-in-a-locally-path-connected-space-is-path

Comment: Thank you both, that clears it up. Didnt quite think it through far enough...

Comment: Seems like this question has been answered in the comments. Perhaps one of you would like to submit an answer that @user2520938 can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(The question is basically answered in the comment)

As a topological manifold is locally path connected, a connected manifold is automatically path connected, as [a connected locally path connected topological space is path connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332108/showing-that-every-connected-open-set-in-a-locally-path-connected-space-is-path)