# Can $\{B(x_0,k)\}_k$ exhaust one complete Riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Recall first the basic knowledga about the geodesic theory.

Let $(M, g)$ be a riemannian manifold of dimension $m,$ with metric
$$
g(x)=\sum g_{j k}(x) d x_{j} \otimes d x_{k}, \quad 1 \leqslant j, k \leqslant m
$$
The length of a path $\gamma:[a, b] \longrightarrow M$ is by definition
$$
\ell(\gamma)=\int_{a}^{b}\left|\gamma^{\prime}(t)\right|_{g} d t=\int_{a}^{b}\left(\sum_{j, k} g_{j k}(\gamma(t)) \gamma_{j}^{\prime}(t) \gamma_{k}^{\prime}(t)\right)^{1 / 2} d t
$$
The geodesic distance of two points $x, y \in M$ is
$\delta(x, y)=\inf _{\gamma} \ell(\gamma) \quad$ over paths $\gamma$ with $\gamma(a)=x, \quad \gamma(b)=y$
if $x, y$ are in the same connected component of $M, \delta(x, y)=+\infty$ otherwise.

Of course, $$
\text  {all closed geodesic balls } \overline{B\left(x_{0}, r\right)} \text { are compact,}
$$ by the Hopf-Rinow.

**Question:Can $\{B(x_0,k)\}_k$ exhaust one complete Riemannian manifold?** i.e.,Does  $\bigcup_k B(x_0,k)=X$
and $\overline{B\left(x_{0}, k\right)}\subset {B\left(x_{0}, k+1\right)}$ hold?

Comment: For your questions, you definitely want $X$ to be connected.  Other than that - where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @JasonDeVito  You are right, under the connectedness assumption, for any point pair $(x,y)$, are their distance  always finite?

Comment: On a complete Riemannian manifold, one consequence of Hopf Rinow is that there is always a minimizing geodesic between two points.  So in this case, the distance is always finite.  That said, I don't think you need completeness.  Via an open/closed argument, you can show that on a connected manifold, any two points are connected by a smooth curve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is true if the manifold is connected.

The first thing to notice is that a manifold is  locally homeomorphic to a euclidean ball and hence locally path connected. Now for connected topological spaces locally path connected implies path connected (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332108/showing-that-every-connected-open-set-in-a-locally-path-connected-space-is-path)) and so connected manifolds are path connected.

In particular, on a connected Riemannian manifold $M$ the distance between any two points is finite, and so $\cup_{k\in\mathbb N} B(x_0,k)=M$ for all $x_0\in M$.

Furthermore $ \overline {B(x_0,k)}\subseteq B(x_0,k+1)$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$:

$(M,\delta$) is a metric space and in any metric space $(X,d)$ it holds that $$\overline{B(x_0,r)}\subseteq \{x\in X:d(x,r)\leq r\}$$ for all $r>0$, which follows from the continuity of the metric. Actually on a Riemannian manifold even equality holds, but this does not matter here.